# javascript are not working on Google chrome

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, google-chrome

On Codeigniter I have a code

HTML

```
//ROOTPATH is the constant Path and $recordId is coming from a loop.

<a href="#" onclick="windowRedirect('<?php echo ROOTPATH; ?>&action=deleteRecord&id=<?php echo $recordId; ?>','Are you sure you want to Delete');return false;">Delete</a>
```

Javascript

```
windowRedirect(url,msg)
{
  if(confirm(msg)) 
  { 
    window.location.href = url;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
}
```

I have written a simple javascript which will redirect url if user click on OK button but I am getting weird problem on Google chrome where this code is working perfectly on Mozila Firefox, IE 8/9 and Applae Safari. Can any one tell me how can I solve this Google Chrome Problem.

Though I have a doubt this script is probably not working because of '#' on the href field but I am not sure.

Comment: `ROOTPATH` is unnecessary. CodeIgniter comes with `site_url()` Furthermore, if you use `site_url()` in conjunction with the `<base>` HTML tag, you never have to use `site_url()` either.

Comment: Yeah what is the "weird problem" in chrome.

Comment: Possibly that you're returning `undefined` if the user confirms the action.

Comment: I use base_url() actually...I just used ROOTPATH for an example.

Comment: paste your html from the page

Comment: The relevant HTML is huge. I don't think it will be helpful if i put here. That is why I specified the problem here as it will be difficult to find the particular one from that huge code. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an working example:

```
<html>
</head>
<script>
function window_redirect(url,msg)
{

  if(confirm(msg))
  { 
    window.location = url;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a onclick="window_redirect('http://www.google.com','Are you sure you want to Delete');" href="#" >Delete</a>

</body>
</html>
```

You forgot to call state 'function' before function, also if you put onclick on a element (link) always put it before href="#" some browsers will not call onclick if that is not the case.

Comment: What version of Google chrome are you using? Give me rendered code, maybe the php part messed up something.

Comment: No Pop up are coming on only Google Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79
And I don't think there is any problem with php as the confirmation pop up is coming in Mozila Firefox, IE 8/9 and Apple Safari. I don't know but only Google Chrome is giving no Pop Ups.

Comment: It's working here on Chrome v21. Maybe you have popups/alerts disabled? Try popping an alert and see if that works..